# Show ToolTip when row hovered and column value matches with another row

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I have a DataGrid that shows every row from my SQL Server table with the status of `Unallocated`.

If a cell or row is hovered, a tooltip needs to show IF there is another row within my database that has the status of `Allocated` with matching `PostCode`, `Trade` and `Date`.

The information in the tool tip needs to show the matching rows `JobNumber`, `PostCode`, `Trade` and `Date`.

If there are no matches then the tool tip should say "No Matches for this Job"

My DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Job Number" Binding="{Binding ID}"/>
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Job" Binding="{Binding JobType}"/>
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Path=JobDate, StringFormat=\{0:dd/MM/yyyy\}}" x:Name="JobDate"/>
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Post Code" Binding="{Binding PostCode}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
      <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Job 1234 Allocated to 'EXAMPLE' has been allocated to a job in this area at 13:00pm" />
      </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
  </DataGridTextColumn>
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Job Status" Binding="{Binding Allocation}"/></DataGrid.Columns>
```

My SQL query:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var UserN = User.name;

    conn.Open();

    string query_search = "SELECT * FROM Jobs WHERE (ID LIKE @ID OR PostCode LIKE @PostCode) AND UserAllocated = '" + UserN + "' AND Allocation = 'Unallocated' AND JobStatus != 'Cancelled' ORDER BY JobDate DESC, PostCode";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query_search, conn);
            
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", "%" + Search.Text + "%");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostCode", "%" + Search.Text + "%");

    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
              
        tblunallocatedjobs.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;          
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```

I am unsure of how to approach this, I attempted comparing SQL queries but with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are displaying data in DataGrid based on the Sql query for a specific condition (through DataGrid.Columns).

> If a cell or row is hovered, a tooltip needs to show IF there is another row within my database that has the status of Allocated with matching PostCode, Trade and Date.
> The information in the tool tip needs to show the matching rows JobNumber, PostCode, Trade and Date. If there are no matches then the tool tip should say "No Matches for this Job".

You need to code a little more to get the desired outcome. In order to use the tooltip, you need to fire the event `DataGridView.CellToolTipTextNeeded`
(Please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.celltooltiptextneeded?view=netframework-4.8, for instructions).

For your specific requirements, you need to include the results of four different queries (i.e., results from queries related to 1. `Unallocated`, 2. `Allocated` with matching `PostCode`, `Trade` and `Date`, 3. Show the matching rows `JobNumber`, `PostCode`, `Trade` and `Date`, and 4. Show for `no matches`), in the tooltip text.